# Sum a part of a column based upon match result

Tags: excel, charts, sum, match

I've been working on this for a few days.

I have 2 columns: Date (A1:A367) and Growth (B1:B367)

Date is consecutive days of the year. Growth is the number for that day.

I am trying to match the date in column A and then sum column B from that row to the end (31st Dec).

I've tried altering the Sum/Index/Match formula but it only works when summing the whole column. This is what I have so far. It only works for date 01/01. I get a #Ref for any other date.

`=SUM(INDEX(B2:B367,0,MATCH(J3,A2:A367,0)))`

I've also tried getting the address for the required cell

`=CELL("address",INDEX(A1:A500,MATCH(K2,A1:A500)))`

Then using that address to populate the =sum formula.

[image: Chart View]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot showing, say, 10 rows? What's in J3?

Comment: B2:B367 is a single column so the second INDEX parameter can't be more than 1.

Comment: Use SUMIFS `=SUMIFS(B2:B367,A2:A367,">="&J3)`

Comment: Amazing Scott, Perfect. Thanks for your help.